# Error on using Chilkat.Zip2

Tags: php, chilkat

Can anybody please let me know, i have used the below code to access COM object...

```
$zip = new COM("Chilkat.Zip2");
echo $zip;
```

but, which shows an like this...

```
    Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'com_exception' with message 'Failed 
to create COM object `ZipActiveX': Invalid syntax ' in 
D:\xampp\htdocs\test\testscript1.php:2 Stack trace: #0 D:\xampp\htdocs\test\testscript1.php(2): com->com('ZipActiveX') 
#1 {main} thrown in D:\xampp\htdocs\test\testscript1.php on line 1
```

please advice me, that do i need to change anything in my php.ini file to access COM?

Comment: what version of windows you using? windows xp or vista/7?

Comment: am using windows XP(local system) and webserver is Linux

Comment: chillkat is for windows server only. you can run localhost using xampp web server to test on your xp machine.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>shut down apache and start in administrator mode if using windows vista or 7.</strike>

**edited:**
chillkat zip activex is for windows server. you can download and install from this url http://www.chilkatsoft.com/download/ZipActiveX.msi

run webserver in windows using xampp adn run locally

xampp download url: http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html